# I get Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') rendering UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

index.js

```
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore((state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === 'ADD') return [...state, action.name];
  return state;
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Item = ({ name, price }) => (<li>{name},${price}</li>)
       
const App = (props) => {
  let nameRef = createRef();
  let priceRef = createRef();

  const add = () => {
    props.add(
      props.items.length +1,
      nameRef.current.value,
      priceRef.current.value,
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {props.items.map(i => (
          <Item key={i.id} name={i.name} price={i.price} />
        ))}
      </ul>

      <input type="text" ref={nameRef} />
      <input type="text" ref={priceRef} />
      <button onClick={add}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const stateToProps = state => {
  return {
    items: state
  }
}

const dispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    add: (id, name, price) => {
      dispatch ({
        type: 'ADD',
        item: { id, name, price }
      })
    }
  }
}

const ReduxApp = connect(stateToProps, dispatchToProps)(App);
export default ReduxApp
```

Error[image]
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

I don't know why the code didn't throw an error on `i.id`, but the issue is that you are pushing `undefined` into the state array each time the `ADD` action is dispatched.

```js
add: (id, name, price) => {
  dispatch ({
    type: 'ADD',
    item: { id, name, price }
  })
}
```

The `action` object has two properties: `type` and `item`, but when the dispatched action is processed in the reducer function, `action.name`, which is `undefined` is appended into the array.

```js
const store = createStore(
  (state = [], action) => {
    if (action.type === 'ADD') return [...state, action.name];
    return state;
  }
);
```

```js
state: [undefined, undefined, undefined, ....etc...]
```

The `state` is selected and injected into the `App` component as `props.items` and when mapped, each array element value is `undefined` and the code attempts to access properties and the error is thrown.

```
<ul>
  {props.items.map(i => (
    <Item
      key={i.id}
      name={i.name} // <-- oops, i is undefined!
      price={i.price}
    />
  ))}
</ul>
```

## Solution

Access the `ADD` action payload correctly. You are using very dated redux patterns, so I'll rewrite portions of the code that align with more conventional redux, which will make upgrading or working with modern redux easier for you.

index.js

```js
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {legacy_createStore as createStore} from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const rootReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD':
      return [...state, action.payload];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Item = ({ name, price }) => <li>{name}, ${price}</li>;

const addItem = (payload) => ({
  type: 'ADD',
  payload
});
       
const App = ({ addItem, items }) => {
  const nameRef = createRef();
  const priceRef = createRef();

  const add = () => {
    addItem({
      id: items.length + 1,
      name: nameRef.current.value,
      price: priceRef.current.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Item key={item.id} name={item.name} price={item.price} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" ref={nameRef} />
      <input type="text" ref={priceRef} />
      <button type="button" onClick={add}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state
});

const mapDispatchToProps =  {
  addItem
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

A more modern version would use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks in lieu of the outdated `connect` Higher Order Component.

App.js

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Item = ({ name, price }) => <li>{name}, ${price}</li>;

const addItem = (payload) => ({
  type: 'ADD',
  payload
});
       
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const items = useSelector(state => state);

  const nameRef = createRef();
  const priceRef = createRef();

  const add = () => {
    dispatch(addItem({
      id: items.length + 1,
      name: nameRef.current.value,
      price: priceRef.current.value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Item key={item.id} name={item.name} price={item.price} />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input type="text" ref={nameRef} />
      <input type="text" ref={priceRef} />
      <button type="button" onClick={add}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```